# Access help and tour from mobile

Tags: support

Just joined, and I want to review the help before asking a question.
Is there a way to get to the help /on mobile/?  I do not see an obvious link.

Answer (score 3):

At the very bottom of the page, the footer contains links to the help sections:

[image]

Screenshot is from Android but it should be similar for iPhones. Note that the help pages are not optimized for mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Since I just had to hunt for this myself in order to provide the link to a new contributor who posted an off-topic question, I think it should be easier to get to.  I suggest putting a link to the help page near the beginning of the tour, and somewhere "above the fold" on the question index.  And links to the "what types" and "what topics" FAQs above the ask question form.